# the ways by which page table entry can become dirty

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, elf, page-tables

The accessed and dirty (A/D) bits inform about a page whether it is accessed or written. when a file is loaded in memory some changes are only in memory which are not still synchronized with file stored on the disk. that page which is modified but not written back is dirty page.

My question is whether this concept also implies on ELF files? 
Can .code, .data also get dirty? if yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is whether this concept also implies on ELF files?

Yes.

> Can .code, .data also get dirty? if yes then how?

The `.code` *usually* doesn't have write permission (only read and execute), and so it *usually* doesn't get dirty.

However, you *can* `mprotect` a `.code` page to be writable, and write to it (this is often used in runtime patching). If you do, the corresponding page will become dirty, and *will stay* dirty because it is mapped with `MAP_PRIVATE` (you generally don't want a running program to change its image on-disk).

You could also get dirty `.code` pages if your binary has text relocations (which often happens when non-`fPIC` code is linked into a shared library on  `ix86`).

Finally, the `.data` pages are modified *all the time* (every time you modify an initialized global variable), and these pages then stay dirty for the duration of the program (again, you generally don't want a running program to modify its on-disk image).

**Update:**

> text/.code relocations with out fpic are those which are made for shared libraries at load time. then it means these relocations make .code dirty before even execution of entry instruction.

Not necessarily. Two cases to consider:

1. `a.out` that directly depends on `foo.so`
2. `a.out` that uses `dlopen` to load `foo.so`

In case 1, you are correct: text relocations in `foo.so` will cause (some of) its `.text` pages to become dirty before the first instruction of `a.out` is executed (note that user-space starts executing from `ld.so` entry, not from `a.out` entry).

In case 2, the `.text` pages will become dirty as part of the `dlopen`, which is long after `main` (which is itself long after the entry instruction).

> when .data pages are modified, in response should .code pages also become dirty for fpic or non fpic?

No: modifying `.data` does not cause `.code` to also become dirty. Why would it?

Comment: thanks nice consolidation. text/.code relocations with out fpic are those which are made for shared libraries at load time. then it means these relocations make .code dirty before even execution of entry instruction. Am I right? when .data pages are modified, in response should .code pages  also become dirty for fpic or non fpic?

Comment: @shami Updated the answer.

Comment: your fpic hint in answer opened new avenue of lot of reading. i was thinking of .data dirtiness due to relocation which should change the addresses used by the .code instructions. but in pic code linker can calculate absolute address from size of .code section and Instruction Pointer offset. so it means .data relocation does not dirty .code. Am I right?